# How to conditionally run one of two functions with tokio::join?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I need to run 4 functions concurrently but one of them is different based on user input.

If I use "if-else" I get "if and else have incompatible types" due to Future.

The only way I see is to make a third function that selects from the other two, but it doesn't allow (to my knowledge) to run concurrently due to awaiting.

Another way is to make two different join! but that seems "code expensive".

What should I do in this situation?

```rust
tokio::join!(
    self.func1(),
    if self.flag() {
        self.func2()
    } else {
        self.func3()
    },
    self.func4(),
    self.func5()
);
```

The function signature is as follows:

```
pub async fn funcN(&self) -> Result<Vec<String>> {
```

Comment: Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=446723ef176a170f0c4f22e9646ca0bb

Answer (score 3):

The probably easiest way is to use a `Box` and dynamic dispatch. For example, this compiles:

```
tokio::join!(
    func1(),
    if flag() {
        Box::pin(func2()) as Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = _>>>
    } else {
        Box::pin(func3()) as Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = _>>>
    },
    func4(),
    func5()
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f288cb88a44d9e29d97a2625e981ea0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` inside an `async` block to produce a single future type from two:

```rust
tokio::join!(
    func1(),
    async {
        if flag() {
            func2().await
        } else {
            func3().await
        }
    },
    func4(),
    func5()
);
```

This has slightly different scheduling than the other answers: the `flag()` call is made part of the future rather than run immediately. If this is undesirable, you could put the boolean result in a variable beforehand.

Other than that, this is much like the `Either` approach, but can generalize to more than two choices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`futures::future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/enum.Either.html) enum:

```
tokio::join!(
    self.func1(),
    if self.flag() {
        Either::Left(self.func2())
    } else {
        Either::Right(self.func3())
    },
    self.func4(),
    self.func5()
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5973a6b4358f1ea959f11a53f3a5196b)